# Openlayers 3 Is it possible to have multiple select interactions?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I recently had a good reason to use two different select interactions on the same map, and am surprised to find that the event handler for the latest applied select interaction is the only one that fires.

Both of these select interactions are using the default condition, a click.

Is there a way to make them both trigger??

Answer (score 1):

Hm, im also using two select interactions and i dont have any problem. I added one to react on pointermove (like hover) and one for click and both select interaction are firing. Be aware to 'name' them different.
Naming is wrong, i just created/initialise two with different vars

```
//select interaction working on click
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
                condition: ol.events.condition.click,
                layers: [layer]               
            });
// select interaction working on "pointermove"
            var selectPointerMove = new ol.interaction.Select({
                condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
                layers: [layer]
            });
            map.addInteraction(selectClick);
            map.addInteraction(selectPointerMove);
```

Comment: Thank you, this narrows down the issue to using the same 'condition' I guess.

Comment: Which `ol` version are you using?

Comment: hi @ryansstack, I have the same problem but it dose not work. https://jsfiddle.net/veung7hc/